# Create link in current place while render component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using an array of objects for rendering cards:

```
someData = [
  {
   title: "some title",
   text: "some text where i need put link on word",
   linkedWord: "where"
 }
]
```

or it can be array of linkedWord.

Then I render my card with this data:

```
 {
   someData.map(item=> {
    <Card data={item} />
 }
)
}
```

The question is, how can I put link on word in Card component?

I'm trying to use split text before expected link and after, but it only works with 1 expected link.

I tried like this:

```
     const [strBefore, setStrBefor] = useState()
    const [strAfter, setStrAfter] = useState()
    const [LinkIndex, setLinkIndex] = useState()



    useEffect(() => {
        if (props.data.link) {
            let test = props.data.title.split(" ")
            test.map((item, index) => {
             if(item === props.data.link) {
                 setLinkIndex(index)
             }
            })
            if(LinkIndex === 0) {
                setStrAfter(test.splice(LinkIndex + 1, test.length).join(' '))
            }
            else if(LinkIndex === test.length) {
                setStrAfter('')
            }
            else {
                setStrBefor(test.splice(0, LinkIndex).join(' '))
                setStrAfter(test.splice(LinkIndex, test.length).join(' '))
            }
        }

    },[LinkIndex])
```

and render:

```
<h3>{strBefore} <a href='#'>{props.data.link}</a> {strAfter}</h3>
```

Comment: Why does it only work within 1?
Post what you have now for setting the link for that word.

Comment: Done update with my code

Comment: You can split the string with expected link part and you can start and end from there and inject link with link part in between.

const parts = text.split(linkedWord); // parts[0] = "some text ", parts[1] = " i need to put link on word";

link = <h3>{parts[0]}<a href='#'>{linkedWord}</a>{parts[1]}</h3>

Comment: but what if i have array of words?

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert link in href:
Instead to do this

```
<h3>{strBefore}<a href='#'>{props.data.link}</a> {strAfter}</h3>
```

You need to do

```
<h3>{strBefore} <a href='{props.data.link}'>something</a> {strAfter}</h3>
```

Comment: that doesnt solve the problem
the problem is, that i need put word, or array of word that i want wrap in <a></a> in text

Answer (score 0):

Solve this proble with marked-react

```
npm i marked-react
```

change key in object

```
someData = [
     {
  text: 'some text [where](https://www.google.com) i need wrap word in link'
    }
   ]
```

in component use Markdown component

```
<Markdown>{props.data.text}</Markdown>
```

and it wrap word on link